# Eclipse can't reference one project from another

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I was cleaning up my desktop, and I deleted a java project file, assuming that Eclipse handled my workspace internally. This is the only change I've made to my code that created this storm.

I have two projects, A and B. Project A references project B. Project B is in project A's build path. However, all of my Java imports that point from A to B `import b.app.utils.etc` are now failing with the error

> The import b cannot be resolved.

What have I done by deleting B from my desktop, and how can I fix it?

I deleted the project directory, which I have a backup of. I just can't get the imports to work now for some reason. I suppose what I need to know is, what was pointing to that directory on my desktop before, and how do I recreate that link to the restored directory in the new location?

Comment: What exactly did you delete? The project directory? A single file? Which file? Is there a backup copy in source control or backup media?

Comment: I deleted the project directory, which I have a backup of. I just can't get the imports to work now for some reason. I suppose what I need to know is, what was pointing to that directory on my desktop before, and how do I recreate that link to the restored directory in the new location?

Comment: Project properties > Java Build Path > SOURCE, then set the directories to point to where you restored the project directory.

Comment: I've tried that before, using Link Source. Is there something specific I need to know, or can I just Link Source > Point to full directory?

Comment: Have you tried _Project > Clean..._ yet?

Comment: Yeah, no luck there either.